# update content of stored column in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a table with 3 columns:
firstname
lastname
fullname

in migration:

```
Schema::create('owners', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id(); 
$table->string('firstname',20);
 $table->string('lastname', 20);
 $table->string('fullname')->storedAs('CONCAT(firstname,lastname)');
 $table->timestamps(); 
});
```

the problem is that i want to change the concatenation order in the controller i tried to use db statement but it doesn't work

-in the controller:

```
$owners= Owner::findOrFail($id);
$owners->update([
'firstname'=>$request['firstname'],
 'lastname' =>$request['lastname'],
 ]); 
DB::statement('UPDATE owners SET fullname AS CONCAT(lastname,firstname) STORED WHERE ID=1 ');
```

I don't want to just use a simple concatenation because the user can change the firstname or the lastname and the order that's why I used storedAs()

any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

The `storedAs` method in the migration creates a generated column in mysql. The value is automatically generated from the column values of the firstname and the lastname. There's no way you can change this via an `UPDATE` statement. You'd have to use an `ALTER TABLE` statement, which would be horrifically bad practice.

If I were you, I'd keep full name display as a model method so you could access it by using `$owner->fullNameFirstLast()` or `$owner->fullNameLastFirst()`

Comment: can i use storedAs() in model any example? I'm not sure it will work, because I want to keep the value stored and it should update automatically if I change firstname or lastname, if not other alternatives to storedAs?

Comment: If you need access to both the `Firstname, Lastname` format and the `Lastname, Firstname` format, you either need 2 `storedAs` columns or concatenate the data at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a new migration in order to change the column, the code would be something like this:

```
Schema::table('owners', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->string('fullname')->storedAs('CONCAT(lastname,firstname)');
});
```

This way the column will be changed on a database level, and no need for the controller query you have added

Comment: it is not possible I have already tried to do this in the controller it gives me the message that the column already exists

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this
1- update your migration to

```
Schema::create('owners', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id(); 
     $table->string('firstname',20);
     $table->string('lastname', 20);
     $table->string('fullname', 56);
     $table->timestamps(); 
    });
```

2- in your controller

```
$owners= Owner::findOrFail($id);
$first_name = $request->firstname ?? $owners->firstname;
$last_name = $request->lastname ?? $owners->lastname;
$full_name = $first_name.' '.$last_name;

$owners->update([
  'firstname'=>$first_name,
  'lastname' =>$last_name,
  'fullname' =>$full_name,
  ]);
```

You can also write it this way

```
DB::statement(DB::raw("UPDATE owners SET firstname = '".$first_name."', lastname = '".$last_name."', fullname = '".$full_name."' WHERE id = $id"));
```

And the same way for your **Create** function as well

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's a simple concatenation it's the same as DB:raw('CONCAT(firstname,lastname) it doesn't update the value of column fullname if I update the value of firstname or lastname